Semi-direct decomposition of a solvable Lie group
(This is a cross-post from this MSE question)
I am searching for a reference or proof to the following fact (asserted at the top of page 2 here).
Let $G$ be a connected, solvable Lie group. Then $G = L \rtimes K$ for closed subgroups $K,L \subset G$ satisfying:

$K$ compact
$L$ normal in $G$
There is some compact normal $T \subset L$ so that $L/T$ is simply connected.

This fact does not appear on wikipedia's list of Lie group decompositions. Most resources I can find are about decompositions of or into semisimple Lie groups (my $G$ is solvable).
I think that I am missing some general fact about the structure of solvable Lie groups. Any help/references are appreciated.

This is directly implied by Theorem 6 in:
A. Malcev, On the theory of the Lie groups in the large, Rec.
Math. [Mat. Sbornik] N.S., 1945, Volume 58, Number 2, 163–
190.
Theorem 6: Let $G$ be a connect solvable Lie group.  Then $G=KL_1\cdots L_nT$ where $K$ is a compact subgroup, $L_i$ is a 1-dimensional subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ for all $i$, $T$ is a compact, central subgroup, $L_i\cdots L_nT$ is normal for all $i$, $L_i\cap L_{i+1}\cdots L_nT=\{e\}$ for all $i$, and $K\cap L_1\cdots L_n T=\{e\}$.
Remark: I tried to write Theorem 6 in the way Malcev wrote it, but did change some notation and language.  In particular, I wrote "normal" instead of "invariant" since that is today's usage, and moved away from "mathfrak" for groups since that font is used more for Lie algebras these days.  I also did not use "vector group" since it might not be known by all readers that it means a 1 parameter subgroup homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.
To get your statement, just let $L=L_1\cdots L_n T$.  Then $L$ is normal and with $G=KL$ and $K\cap L=\{e\}$ you obtain $G=K\ltimes L$ with $L/T\approx L_1\cdots L_n\cong \mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible (and so simply-connected).
Theorem 6 is a step in the proof of Malcev's Theorem (ref. ibid): Every Lie group $G$ with finitely many components has a maximal compact subgroup $K$, unique up to inner automorphisms, and $G$ is homeomorphic to $K\times E$ where $E$ is a Euclidean space.
To get Malcev's theorem, loosely speaking, start with Levi's decomposition of $G$ into semisimple and solvable subgroups.  Apply Cartan's decomposition of the semisimple subgroup into compact and Euclidean subgroups.  Then apply Theorem 6 to the solvable subgroup to get the result.
A nice corollary of Theorem 6, that is not immediately obvious from the statement you are asking about, is that your solvable connected $G$ is homeomorphic to a product of Euclidean lines and circles.
